# How can I get manager's value via admin SDK

Tags: google-apps-script, sdk, admin, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to use the below function

```
function getuser() {
 var userEmail = 'xxx@xxx.com';
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);
  Logger.log(user.relations);
}
```

I can get

```
[{type=manager, value=yyy@xxx.com}]
```

If I only need output 'yyy@xxx.com'

Any ideas?
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `relations` is an array that can contain more than one element
- Each element contains two key-value pairs
- To access the value related to a key, you need to address a specific array element or loop through all array elements

**Sample**

```js
function getuser() {
  var userEmail = 'xxx@xxx.com';
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);
  var relations = user.relations;
  for (var i =0; i < relations.length; i++){
    Logger.log(user.relations[i].value);
  }
}
```